# Converting JavaScript into Iframe to use in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, iframe, sharepoint, embed

I have tried adding this JavaScript embed code to my SharePoint page and it was saying it will only accept Iframe tags. The code is working fine in JS W3 School. Can anyone please help ?

```html
<div id="ja-jobs-widget"></div>
<script>
    var _jaJobsSettings = {
        key: "bbhc36kiqfoudkoc4yd7qaihf4"
    };
</script>
<script src="//apps.jobadder.com/widgets/v1/jobs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I switched the snippet language to html and it seems to run fine here in this page now. Snippets do run in iframes so this may or may not help you

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553584/using-javascript-to-write-an-iframe-for-a-widget-best-practices-limitations

Comment: `<iframe src='yourURLHere.php'></iframe>` is how you assign a webpage to an iframe. It has to be a full webpage that generates HTML. You can do like `<iframe src='yourURLHere.html#idToTarget'></iframe>` to just load partial content on a full page, though.